# Better Database Destructing

Tags: mysql, database-design, table

what is the best way to destruct database tables,

suppose that we have two tables `TRADER` and `PRODUCTS`, what is the best way to destruct the tables:

1. create `TRADER_ID` Column  in `PRODUCT_TABLE`
2. make a separate table consist on `TRADER_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the trader can have different products and products are linked to different trader.

You need a relationship tables Trader_Products, which will represent the n:m relationship

So option 2 is the right answer.

Comment: what if the product can link with only one trader ? @nbk

Comment: that doesn't matter. your version 1 is only possible, when one trader had exclusive access  to  products that no other could have  also known as 1:n relationships. but in your scenario it is usually a n:m. if you want a exclusive access for one trader you must implement it in your program, that has nothing to do with the databse